# C# Get true path of current directory

Tags: c#, file, file-io, path

I have a project, built with Visual Web Developer 2008. I want to be able to extract (with C#), the current folder the project is in now. Until now I had to hard code the true path.

This project is hosted on my computer.

For example, the path I would like to generate:

```
C:\Users\Guy\Desktop\Project
```

Thanks! Guy

Comment: Do you mean the location of the project 'I.e. the `.cs`' file? or the build output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Directory Of Base Assembly Resolver:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Answer (score 2):

The safest way:

```
string temp = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are only reading, then

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
```

works. But if you want to write to, then you'd have to go with:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Or you will get an

```
{"URI formats are not supported."}
```

exception because your path is

```
file:\\C:\\Projects\
```

instead of

```
C:\\Projects
```

Answer (score 1):

To map a page (or Virtual Directory) to the filesystem location (at runtime) you can user `Server.MapPath("/")`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
```